# Error:$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, model, classification

I'm trying to compare two classification models and my code has given me "Error:$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors. Any thoughts on how to debug this?

Here's my R programming code:

```
results<-resamples(list(testindex["svm.pred"], testindex["rpart.pred"]))
```

Comment: Is this a base R function? If not, please provide the package.

Comment: install.packages("caret")